# EF LINQ - Select only parent Entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm faced with an interesting issue.

I have a Node entity.  Nodes may or may not have Children, and also may or may not have a parent.

For my UI, when a user searches for a Node, I'd like to only return the Parent if the search results contain both the parent and one or many of its children (since the Parent has a Children Navigation Property).

**My result when I search for a name that contains "ParentA":**

- ParentA
- ParentA_ChildA
- ParentA_ChildB

**Desired result:**

- ParentA  (because **ParentA.Children** will contain ***ParentA_ChildA*** and ***ParentA_ChildB***)

**This is my current LINQ Query:**

```
var results = await dbContext.Nodes.
                        Include(c => c.Parent).
                        Where(c => c.NodeName.Contains(query)).
                        OrderBy(n => n.NodeName).
                        ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, pageSize);
```

**Node Entity:**

```
public class Node
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Node Name")]
    public string NodeName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public Nullable<long> ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Node Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Any` method like this: `c.Children.Any(x => x.NodeName.Contains(query))`

```
var results = await dbContext.Nodes.
                        Include(c => c.Parent).
                        Where(c => c.NodeName.Contains(query)).
                        Where(c => c.Children.Any(x => x.NodeName.Contains(query))).
                        OrderBy(n => n.NodeName).
                        ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, pageSize);
```

Comment: This works great.  The only thing it doesn't return is a Node that doesn't have any children.  Is it possible to to do so?

Comment: I figured it out, I modified the second WHERE clause to:
Where(c => c.Children.Any(x => x.NodeName.Contains(query)) || !c.Parent.NodeName.Contains(query))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include parent, you can search children and return the parent. If you need, you can return children as well.

```
dbContext.Nodes.Where(
     n =>n.NodeName.Contains(query)) || n.Children.Any(
         c=>c.NodeName.Contains(query))).
                    OrderBy(n => n.NodeName).
                    ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, pageSize);
```

Comment: This solution results in getting all the children, as well as the parent.  The solution I was looking for was getting only the parent.

Answer (score 0):

please try this....

```
dbContext.Nodes
     .Where(c => c.NodeName.Contains(query))
     .Select(c=>GetParentOrSelf(c,query))
     .OrderBy(n => n.NodeName)
     .ToPagedListAsync(page ?? 1, pageSize);    


private Node GetParentOrSelf(Node n)
{
    if (n.Parent==null)
        return n;
    else
    {
        if (n.Parent.NodeName.Contains(query))
            return GetParentOrSelf(n.Parent,query);
        else
            return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution generates an exception because the written method is not recognized by LINQ to Entities.

Comment: my mistake...didn't realize while posting that it was not regular linq....sorry about that...